# When testing Chainlink CCIP with Router.sol, what address should the onRamp be?

Tags: testing, chainlink, foundry

I'm trying to write unit tests for a Chainlink CCIPSender contract, but as far as I can tell it is reverting when calling `getFee()` to pay for the transaction.

In my test I call `applyRampUpdates()` from Chainlink CCIP's `Router.sol`. I have to specify a `destination chain selector` and an `onRamp` address. For the address, I have tried msg.sender, the receiver contract and the router itself.

When I run my test, it reverts during the `getFee()` call.

This line in `Router.getFee()` implies I have to implement my own `onRamp` contract with custom `getFee()` logic:

`return IEVM2AnyOnRamp(onRamp).getFee(destinationChainSelector, message);`

Is that correct or am I wrong?

Here is my test:

```
 modifier fundLinkToRevealerAndApprove() {
        vm.prank(msg.sender);
        link.transfer(REVEALER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.deal(REVEALER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.prank(REVEALER);
        link.approve(address(ccidSender), oraclePayment);
        _;
    }

    modifier authorizedSenders() {
        address[] memory authorizedAddresses = new address[](1);
        authorizedAddresses[0] = REVEALER;

        vm.prank(0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f);
        operator.setAuthorizedSenders(authorizedAddresses);
        _;
    }

    modifier setDestinationSelectorAndReceiverAddress() {
        vm.startPrank(anvilAccount);
        ccidSender.setCcidDestinationSelector(ccidDestinationSelector);
        ccidSender.setCcidReceiver(ccidReceiver);
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    modifier applyRampUpdates() {
        vm.startPrank(msg.sender);
        Router.OnRamp memory newOnRamp = Router.OnRamp({
            destChainSelector: 16015286601757825753, // Sepolia
            onRamp: ccidReceiver
        });
        Router.OnRamp[] memory newOnRampArray = new Router.OnRamp[](1);
        newOnRampArray[0] = newOnRamp;

        router.applyRampUpdates(newOnRampArray, new Router.OffRamp[](0), new Router.OffRamp[](0));
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    function testFulfillAndSend()
        public
        fundLinkToRevealerAndApprove
        authorizedSenders
        setDestinationSelectorAndReceiverAddress
        applyRampUpdates
    {
        vm.startPrank(REVEALER);
        ccidSender.requestStatus(REVEALEE);
        // bytes32 requestId = ccidSender.getLatestSentRequestId();
        bytes32 constantRequestId = 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe;
        uint8 kycUserStatus = 1;
        uint40 nonZeroKycTimestamp = 1658845449;
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(constantRequestId, kycUserStatus, nonZeroKycTimestamp);
        operator.fulfillOracleRequest2(
            constantRequestId,
            oraclePayment,
            address(ccidSender),
            bytes4(keccak256("fulfill(bytes32,uint8,uint40)")),
            block.timestamp + 5 minutes,
            data
        );
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
```

The test function I am testing is `testFulfillAndSend()`.

Here are the functions in my Sender contract that it calls:

```
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, Status _status, uint40 _kycTimestamp)
        external
        override
        recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        if (_status == Status.KYCUser) {
            if (_kycTimestamp == 0) {
                revert CCIDSender__KycTimestampShouldNotBeZeroForKycUser();
            }
        } else {
            if (_kycTimestamp != 0) {
                revert CCIDSender__KycTimestampShouldBeZeroForNonKycUser();
            }
        }

        Request storage request = _requests[_requestId];
        request.kycTimestamp = _kycTimestamp;
        request.isFulfilled = true;
        request.isHumanAndUnique = _status != Status.NotFound;
        request.isKYCUser = _status == Status.KYCUser;
        latestFulfilledRequestId[request.revealee] = _requestId;

        emit Fulfilled(_requestId, request.revealer, request.revealee, _status, _kycTimestamp);
        sendKycStatusToCcidReceiver(_status);
    }

    function sendKycStatusToCcidReceiver(Status _status) internal {
        string memory statusString = statusToString(_status);
        Client.EVM2AnyMessage memory message = Client.EVM2AnyMessage({
            receiver: abi.encode(ccidReceiver),
            data: abi.encode(statusString),
            tokenAmounts: new Client.EVMTokenAmount[](0),
            extraArgs: "",
            feeToken: link
        });

        uint64 destinationChainSelector = ccidDestinationSelector;

        uint256 fees = IRouterClient(router).getFee(destinationChainSelector, message);
        LinkTokenInterface(link).approve(address(router), fees);

        IRouterClient(router).ccipSend(destinationChainSelector, message);
    }
```

Here are the final parts of my test log:

```
├─ [39126] Operator::fulfillOracleRequest2(0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe, 100000000000000000 [1e17], CCIDSender: [0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3], 0xccd8682400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 301, 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062dff909) 
    │   ├─ emit OracleResponse(requestId: 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe)
    │   ├─ [33555] CCIDSender::fulfill(0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe, 1, 1658845449 [1.658e9]) 
    │   │   ├─ emit ChainlinkFulfilled(id: 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe)
    │   │   ├─ emit Fulfilled(_requestId: 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe, _revealer: REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], _revealee: REVEALEE: [0x50FA752360aD481DDbE824f39Cbc32FA9FD9458d], _status: 1, _kycTimestamp: 1658845449 [1.658e9])
    │   │   ├─ [6860] Router::getFee(16015286601757825753 [1.601e19], EVM2AnyMessage { receiver: 0x000000000000000000000000c32c3d415b8597604342351d7246f85e29ad6efb, data: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084b59435f55534552000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, tokenAmounts: [], feeToken: 0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76, extraArgs: 0x }) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   ├─ [0] ccidReceiver::getFee(16015286601757825753 [1.601e19], EVM2AnyMessage { receiver: 0x000000000000000000000000c32c3d415b8597604342351d7246f85e29ad6efb, data: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084b59435f55534552000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, tokenAmounts: [], feeToken: 0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76, extraArgs: 0x }) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   │   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
    │   │   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
    │   └─ ← false
    ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank() 
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()
```

Whatever address I specify as the `onRamp` in my test's `applyRampUpdates` modifier is the address that `getFee()` attempts to be called from after the Router, so in that test log you can see the `ccidReceiver` address is getting called.

I have to call `applyRampUpdates()` on the Router in my test because I need to specify a `destinationChainSelector`.

If anyone could please offer any advice as to what I should be doing, I would be very grateful. To summarize: I am trying to test a CCIP Sender contract that appears to be reverting when calling `getFee()` and I am unclear about what address should be the `onRamp`, and the reasons for all of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getFee()` call comes from the [EVM2EVMOnRamp.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/ccip/blob/ccip-develop/contracts/src/v0.8/ccip/onRamp/EVM2EVMOnRamp.sol#L505) smart contract.

So you need to either provide its actual address on the source blockchain, assuming you are using the `forking` method for testing, or with any other setup you will need to deploy it (or its mocked version) during the test setup.